# NPM statistics?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Is there any way that would help me in getting answers to few questions like below?

1. Total number of packages depending on xyz module in entire npm registry (not my local machine)?
2. Total number of modules/packages importing/exporting xyz module? etc?

If nothing is available, I am okay to write a script but just wanted to check if there has been some ready-made stats available on it or else some script already available so that I don't re-invent the wheel. I could not find any.

Comment: eg: https://www.npmjs.com/browse/depended/browserify ?

Comment: Yes similar, but its not giving me any count or so.. just the names depending on each one.